# Not detecting short power button press

Tags: java, android, keypress, onkeydown, onkeypress

I want to detect when the power button has been pressed (not long press) in my app.

I'm using the following code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
            Log.d("mytag", "keycode_power");
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

However, nothing prints to log. I've also tried:

```
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
            Log.d("mytag", "power off");
        }
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }
```

but that doesn't work either.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm No Expert, But I Don't Think That The Power Button Counts As A Keypress